# form submitting only with one field

Tags: php, forms

I have this code to enter data and check all fields are correct. The validation works well but if i just input in last name field and click submit, the form submits and it shows username/email already registered and if i leave the last name field blank the form does not submits. What i want is the form should only submit when all the fields are entered correctly

```
<?php
include'connect.php';
require_once './config.php';
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $lnameErr = $fnameErr = $passErr = "";
$name = $email = $lname = $fname = $pass = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
 $nameErr = "Username is required";
} else {
 $name = ($_POST["username"]);
 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{5,30}$/",$name)) {
  $nameErr = "6 to 30 characters,alphanumeric, underscore & dots only";
}
}

 if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
 $emailErr = "Email is required";
 } else {
 $email = ($_POST["email"]);
 // check if e-mail address is well-formed
 if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   $emailErr = "Invalid email address"; 
 }
 }


 if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
 $passErr = "Password is required";
 }else {
 $pass = ($_POST["password"]);
 if (!preg_match("/(?=^.{8,30}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/",$pass)) {
  $passErr = "Alphanumeric, Upper & Lower Case & Special Charcters required";
 }
 }  

 if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
 $fnameErr = "First Name is required";
 } else {
  $fname = ($_POST["fname"]);
  if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]{3,30}$/",$fname)) {
  $fnameErr = "3 to 30 characters, aplphabets only";
 }
 }
 if (empty($_POST["lname"])) {
 $lnameErr = "Last Name is required";
 } else {
 $lname = ($_POST["lname"]);
 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]{3,30}$/",$lname)) {
  $lnameErr = "3 to 30 characters, aplphabets only";
 }


else{
if (isset($_POST["sub"])) {
 $fname = trim($_POST["fname"]);
 $lname = trim($_POST["lname"]);
 $name = trim($_POST["username"]);
 $pass = trim($_POST["password"]);
 $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
 $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count from users where email = :email_id or username = :username_id ";
 try {
 $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->bindValue(":email_id", $email);
 $stmt->bindValue(":username_id", $name);
 $stmt->execute();
 $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

 if ($result[0]["count"] > 0) {
  echo"<div>E-mail or Username Already Registered</div>";
 } else {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `firstname`, `lastname`) VALUES " . "( :name, :pass, :email, :fname, :lname)";
  $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindValue(":fname", $fname);
  $stmt->bindValue(":lname", $lname);
  $stmt->bindValue(":name", $name);
  $stmt->bindValue(":pass", md5($pass));
  $stmt->bindValue(":email", $email);
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->rowCount();


  if ($result > 0) {
  require_once "PHPMailerAutoload.php";       
$lastID = $DB->lastInsertId();

$message = '<html><head>
<title>Message</title>
</head>
<body>';
$message .= '<p>Hello!</p>';

$message .= "</body></html>";


// php mailer code starts
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port = 587;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username = 'example@example.com';
$mail->Password = 'Password';
$mail->SetFrom('example@example.com', 'Name');
$mail->AddAddress($email);
$mail->Subject = trim("Verification");
$mail->MsgHTML($message);

try {
$mail->send();
header('Location: welcome.php');
} 
catch (Exception $ex) {
$msg = $ex->getMessage();
$msgType = "warning";
}
} else {
$msg = "Failed to create User";
$msgType = "warning";
}
}
} catch (Exception $ex) {
echo $ex->getMessage();
}
}
}
}
}
?>


<form id="defaultForm" action="html.php" method="post">
<label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="fname"><span style="color: red;" class="error"><?php echo $fnameErr;?></span><br>
<label>Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="lname"><span style="color: red;" class="error"><?php echo $lnameErr;?></span><br>
<label>Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username"><span style="color: red;" class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span><br>
<label>E-mail</label>
<input type="text" name="email"><span style="color: red;" class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span><br>
<label>Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password"><span style="color: red;" class="error"><?php echo $passErr;?></span><br>
<button type="submit" name="sub">Submit!</button>
```

Comment: This part is wrong: `else{
if (isset($_POST["sub"])) {`  The else is following the if from the `lname`'s `preg_match`

Comment: form is not closed

Comment: @PhiterFernandes if i close it at the end it says unexpected else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off... i'll like to implore you to indent your code... Looking at your code, the problem is tied to your lastname variable as the submission logic itself is inside this scope.

Currently your code looks like this

```
 if (empty($_POST["lname"])) {
  $lnameErr = "Last Name is required";
 } 
else {
    $lname = ($_POST["lname"]);
   if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]{3,30}$/",$lname)) {
    $lnameErr = "3 to 30 characters, aplphabets only";
   }
   else{
  if (isset($_POST["sub"])) {
    //Submission logic here
    }
  }
}
```

Take out the submission logic from the lastname block and try this

```
 if (empty($_POST["lname"])) {
  $lnameErr = "Last Name is required";
 } 
else {
    $lname = ($_POST["lname"]);
   if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]{3,30}$/",$lname)) {
    $lnameErr = "3 to 30 characters, aplphabets only";
   }
}

if(empty($lnameErr) && empty($otherError) && empty($anotherError))
{
    //Move Submission logic here
}
else {
   //Display errors
}
```

Your new code should look like this

```
<?php
include'connect.php';
require_once './config.php';
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $lnameErr = $fnameErr = $passErr = "";
$name = $email = $lname = $fname = $pass = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
    $nameErr = "Username is required";
  } 
  else {
   $name = ($_POST["username"]);
   if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{5,30}$/",$name)) {
      $nameErr = "6 to 30 characters,alphanumeric, underscore & dots only";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
  } 
  else {
   $email = ($_POST["email"]);
   // check if e-mail address is well-formed
   if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
     $emailErr = "Invalid email address"; 
   }
  }
  if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
    $passErr = "Password is required";
  }
  else {
   $pass = ($_POST["password"]);
   if (!preg_match("/(?=^.{8,30}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/",$pass)) {
    $passErr = "Alphanumeric, Upper & Lower Case & Special Charcters required";
   }
  }  

  if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
    $fnameErr = "First Name is required";
  } 
  else {
    $fname = ($_POST["fname"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]{3,30}$/",$fname)) {
    $fnameErr = "3 to 30 characters, aplphabets only";
   }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["lname"])) {
    $lnameErr = "Last Name is required";
  } 
  else {
    $lname = ($_POST["lname"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]{3,30}$/",$lname)) {
      $lnameErr = "3 to 30 characters, aplphabets only";
    }
  }

  if(empty($lnameErr) && empty($otherError) && empty($anotherError) && isset($_POST["sub"]))
  {
      //Move Submission logic here
       $fname = trim($_POST["fname"]);
       $lname = trim($_POST["lname"]);
       $name = trim($_POST["username"]);
       $pass = trim($_POST["password"]);
       $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
       $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count from users where email = :email_id or username = :username_id ";
       try {
         $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
         $stmt->bindValue(":email_id", $email);
         $stmt->bindValue(":username_id", $name);
         $stmt->execute();
         $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

        if ($result[0]["count"] > 0) {
          echo"<div>E-mail or Username Already Registered</div>";
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `firstname`, `lastname`) VALUES " . "( :name, :pass, :email, :fname, :lname)";
            $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindValue(":fname", $fname);
            $stmt->bindValue(":lname", $lname);
            $stmt->bindValue(":name", $name);
            $stmt->bindValue(":pass", md5($pass));
            $stmt->bindValue(":email", $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->rowCount();

            if ($result > 0) {
              require_once "PHPMailerAutoload.php";       
              $lastID = $DB->lastInsertId();
              $message = '<html><head>
              <title>Message</title>
              </head>
              <body>';
              $message .= '<p>Hello!</p>';

              $message .= "</body></html>";


              // php mailer code starts
              $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
              $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
              $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
              $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
              $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
              $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
              $mail->Port = 587;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
              $mail->Username = 'example@example.com';
              $mail->Password = 'Password';
              $mail->SetFrom('example@example.com', 'Name');
              $mail->AddAddress($email);
              $mail->Subject = trim("Verification");
              $mail->MsgHTML($message);

              try {
                $mail->send();
                header('Location: welcome.php');
              } 
              catch (Exception $ex) {
                $msg = $ex->getMessage();
                $msgType = "warning";
              }
            } 
            else {
              $msg = "Failed to create User";
              $msgType = "warning";
            }
          }
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
  }
  else {
     //Display errors
  }

}
?>


<form id="defaultForm" action="html.php" method="post">
<label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="fname"><span style="color: red;" class="error"><?php echo $fnameErr;?></span><br>
<label>Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="lname"><span style="color: red;" class="error"><?php echo $lnameErr;?></span><br>
<label>Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username"><span style="color: red;" class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span><br>
<label>E-mail</label>
<input type="text" name="email"><span style="color: red;" class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span><br>
<label>Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password"><span style="color: red;" class="error"><?php echo $passErr;?></span><br>
<button type="submit" name="sub">Submit!</button>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: it says unexpected && when i move submission logic

Comment: If you look at it clearly, i didnt only move the submission logic, i also structured it accordingly... I'll post the full edited code in a bit for you to see @MahimParsai

Comment: Great, dont forget to choose it as an answer